# i want to trace a variable to see it changing

Tags: android, trace, android-sensors, heading

I am new to  java for android and come from an actionscript 3.0 background.  I am playing with the sensor manager and want to trace my direction to see if its working and such.. below is the code i am using to detect a change in direction/heading and i am wondering how to actually see my direction variable change in real time either via a trace or a text out put right on the display of my device:

```
    SensorEventListener listener = new SensorEventListener(){

            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent evt) {
                float vals[] = evt.values;
                float direction = vals[0];

            }
```

any help is greatly appreciated by this novice..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your code is in an Activity class, one thing you could do is:

```
 @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent evt) {
            float vals[] = evt.values;
            float direction = vals[0];
            setTitle("Direction = " + direction);
        }
```

This will display the direction on the Activity's title bar.

If you want to record the values of direction, do this instead:

```
     @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent evt) {
            float vals[] = evt.values;
            float direction = vals[0];
            Log.d("A Log Tag", "Direction = " + direction);
        }
```

That will log the values to LogCat, which you can view in eclipse.